# Firefox security with NoScript

Tags: firefox

If I'm too annoyed by NoScript's default white listing mechanic and I would only use this addon with the "allow scripts globally" option enabled, does it still make sense to have NoScript installed?

In other words: Do the other benefits that NoScript provides outweigh the potentially bigger attack surface that comes from installing this addon?

Comment: Since the point of NoScript is to block scripts unless the script or the site is whitelisted, I don't see how setting "Allow scripts globally" is all that different from disabling or uninstalling NoScript. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it makes a lot of sense.

Firefox does not have an XSS filter, but noscript provides one.

While browser-side XSS filters are not an ideal solution to XSS and can possibly be bypassed, they do catch a great number of reflected XSS attacks. As those are one of the most common web attacks, it is good to have some client-side protection against them (this is even true if you are careful clicking on untrusted links; XSS payloads can also be submitted via forms from websites which you sort-of trust).

Additionally, noscript provides protection against clickjacking. It also claims to have limited protections against CSRF and that it automatically adds the secure flag to cookies.

Weighting these benefits against the downsides of installing third-party software into your browser is difficult, but just the XSS protection would be worth it to me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, even if you enable "*Allow Scripts Globally (dangerous)*", which is not recomended, but it says clearly that it is *dangerous*, NoScript will protect  you from XSS.

I have uploaded vulnerable php file on my server, enabled "*Allow Scripts Globally (dangerous)*", after that NoScript gave me a warning:

> NoScript filtered a potential cross-site scripting (XSS) attempt from
>   ...

If you open console, you will see *NoScript InjectionChecker*

[NoScript InjectionChecker] HTML injection:

```
<script
matches <[^\w<>]*(?:[^<>"'\s]*:)?[^\w<>]*(?:\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?s\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?c\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?r\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?p\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?t|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?f\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?o\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?r\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?m|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?s\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?t\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?y\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?l\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?s\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?v\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?g|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?m\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?r\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?q\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?u\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e|(?:\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?l\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?n\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?k|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?o\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?b\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?j\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?c\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?t|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?m\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?b\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?d|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?p\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?p\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?l\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?t|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?p\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?r\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?m|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i?\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?f\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?r\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?m\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?b\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?s\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?b\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?o\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?d\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?y|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?m\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?t\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?m\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a?\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?g\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e?|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?v\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?d\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?o|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?u\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?d\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?o|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?b\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?n\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?d\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?n\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?g\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?s|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?s\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?t|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?s\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?n\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?d\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?x|\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?n\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?i\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?m\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?a\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?t\W*(?:\/[*/][\s\S]*)?e)[^>\w])|['"\s\0/](?:formaction|style|background|src|lowsrc|ping|on(?:m(?:o(?:z(?:browser(?:beforekey(?:down|up)|afterkey(?:down|up))|(?:network(?:down|up)loa|accesskeynotfoun)d|pointerlock(?:change|error)|(?:orientation|time)change|fullscreen(?:change|error)|interrupt(?:begin|end)|key(?:down|up)onplugin)|use(?:(?:lea|mo)ve|o(?:ver|ut)|enter|wheel|down|up)|ve(?:start|end)?)|a(?:p(?:se(?:tmessagestatus|ndmessage)|message(?:slisting|update)|folderlisting|getmessage)req|rk)|essage)|c(?:o(?:n(?:nect(?:i(?:on(?:statechanged|available)|ng)|ed)?|t(?:rol(?:lerchange|select)|extmenu)|figurationchange)|m(?:p(?:osition(?:update|start|end)|lete)|mand(?:update)?)|py)|h(?:a(?:r(?:ging(?:time)?change|acteristicchanged)|nge)|ecking)|a(?:n(?:play(?:through)?|cel)|(?:llschang|ch)ed|rdstatechange)|u(?:rrent(?:channel|source)changed|echange|t)|l(?:i(?:rmodechange|ck)|ose)|(?:fstate|ell)change)|p(?:o(?:inter(?:l(?:ock(?:change|error)|eave)|o(?:ver|ut)|cancel|enter|down|move|up)|p(?:up(?:hid(?:den|ing)|show(?:ing|n))|state)|ster)|a(?:i(?:ring(?:con(?:firmation|sent)req|aborted)|nt)|ge(?:hide|show)|(?:st|us)e)|u(?:ll(?:vcard(?:listing|entry)|phonebook)req|sh(?:subscriptionchange)?)|r(?:o(?:pertychange|gress)|eviewstatechange)|(?:(?:ending|ty|s)chang|ic(?:hang|tur))e|lay(?:ing)?|hoto)|d(?:e(?:vice(?:p(?:roximity|aired)|(?:orienta|mo)tion|(?:unpaire|foun)d|change|light)|l(?:ivery(?:success|error)|eted)|activate)|i(?:s(?:c(?:hargingtimechange|onnect(?:ing|ed)?)|playpasskeyreq|abled)|aling)|r(?:a(?:g(?:e(?:n(?:ter|d)|xit)|(?:gestur|leav)e|start|drop|over)?|in)|op)|ata(?:setc(?:omplete|hanged)|(?:availabl|chang)e|error)?|urationchange|ownloading|blclick)|s(?:t(?:a(?:t(?:uschanged|echange)|lled|rt)|o(?:rage(?:areachanged)?|p)|k(?:sessione|comma)nd)|e(?:lect(?:ionchange|start)?|ek(?:ing|ed)|n(?:ding|t)|t)|ou(?:rce(?:(?:clos|end)ed|open)|nd(?:start|end))|c(?:(?:anningstate|ostatus)changed|roll)|pe(?:akerforcedchange|ech(?:start|end))|u(?:ccess|spend|bmit)|h(?:utter|ow))|r(?:e(?:s(?:ourcetimingbufferfull|u(?:m(?:ing|e)|lt)|ize|et)|mo(?:ve(?:sourcebuffer|track)|te(?:resume|hel)d)|ad(?:y(?:statechange)?|success|error)|c(?:orderstatechange|eived)|questmediaplaystatus|pea(?:tEven)?t|loadpage|trieving)|ow(?:s(?:inserted|delete)|e(?:nter|xit))|(?:(?:adiost)?ate|t)change|ds(?:dis|en)abled)|a(?:n(?:imation(?:iteration|start|end)|tennaavailablechange)|d(?:d(?:sourcebuffer|track)|apter(?:remov|add)ed)|ttribute(?:(?:write|read)req|changed)|fter(?:(?:scriptexecu|upda)te|print)|b(?:solutedeviceorientation|ort)|ctiv(?:estatechanged|ate)|udio(?:process|start|end)|2dpstatuschanged|lerting)|Moz(?:S(?:wipeGesture(?:(?:May)?Start|Update|End)?|crolledAreaChanged)|M(?:agnifyGesture(?:Update|Start)?|ouse(?:PixelScroll|Hittest))|EdgeUI(?:C(?:omplet|ancel)|Start)ed|RotateGesture(?:Update|Start)?|(?:Press)?TapGesture|AfterPaint)|b(?:e(?:for(?:e(?:(?:scriptexecu|activa)te|e(?:ditfocus|victed)|u(?:nload|pdate)|p(?:aste|rint)|c(?:opy|ut))|deactivate)|gin(?:Event)?)|u(?:fferedamountlow|sy)|oun(?:dary|ce)|l(?:ocked|ur)|roadcast)|DOM(?:Node(?:Inserted(?:IntoDocument)?|Removed(?:FromDocument)?)|(?:CharacterData|Subtree)Modified|A(?:ttrModified|ctivate)|Focus(?:Out|In)|MouseScroll)|w(?:eb(?:kit(?:Animation(?:Iteration|Start|End)|animation(?:iteration|start|end)|(?:TransitionE|transitione)nd)|socket)|a(?:it|rn)ing|heel)|e(?:n(?:ter(?:pincodereq)?|(?:crypt|abl)ed|d(?:Event|ed)?)|m(?:ergencycbmodechange|ptied)|(?:itbroadcas|vic)ted|rror(?:update)?|xit)|f(?:o(?:rm(?:change|input)|cus(?:out|in)?)|ullscreen(?:change|error)|i(?:lterchange|nish)|a(?:cesdetect|il)ed|requencychange|etch)|l(?:o(?:ad(?:e(?:d(?:meta)?data|nd)|ing(?:error|done)?|start)?|s(?:tpointer|e)capture)|(?:anguage|evel)change|y)|o(?:(?:(?:rientation|tastatus)chang|(?:ff|n)lin)e|b(?:expasswordreq|solete)|verflow(?:changed)?|pen)|t(?:o(?:uch(?:cancel|start|move|end)|ggle)|ime(?:update|out)|e(?:rminate|xt)|ransitionend|ypechange)|u(?:p(?:date(?:(?:fou|e)nd|ready|start)?|gradeneeded)|s(?:erproximity|sdreceived)|n(?:derflow|load))|v(?:rdisplay(?:(?:dis)?connect|presentchange)|o(?:ice(?:schanged|change)|lumechange)|ersionchange)|g(?:amepad(?:(?:dis)?connected|button(?:down|up)|axismove)|(?:otpointercaptur|roupchang)e|et)|h(?:e(?:adphoneschange|l[dp])|(?:fp|id)statuschanged|ashchange|olding)|i(?:cc(?:(?:info)?change|(?:un)?detected)|n(?:coming|stall|valid|put))|n(?:o(?:tificationcl(?:ick|ose)|update|match)|ewrdsgroup)|SVG(?:(?:Unl|L)oad|Resize|Scroll|Zoom)|key(?:press|down|up)|(?:AppComman|Loa)d|Request|zoom))[\s\0]*=

[NoScript XSS] Blocked susspisious request: [https://-mywebsite-/index.php?name=%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(xss);%3C/script%3E]
```

This filter works even if you have that website whitelisted.